# SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error) javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to develop an application with jersey, spring and hibernate. I hope that someone can help me to resolve this problem.
I get this exception when I try to extract an Object from my database and transform it to xml element.

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: ma.noyauSolution.entities.Region@22b8be54 -> ma.noyauSolution.entities.Province@38677a45 -> ma.noyauSolution.entities.Region@22b8be54]
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: ma.noyauSolution.entities.Region@22b8be54 -> ma.noyauSolution.entities.Province@38677a45 -> ma.noyauSolution.entities.Region@22b8be54]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:179)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:157)
... 27 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: ma.noyauSolution.entities.Region@22b8be54 -> ma.noyauSolution.entities.Province@38677a45 -> ma.noyauSolution.entities.Region@22b8be54
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.pushObject(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
... 32 more
```

This is my beans Region and Province :

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="T_REGION")
public class Region implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idRegion;
@Column(name = "NOM_REGION", nullable = false, length = 30, unique = true)
private String nomRegion;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "region", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@XmlTransient
private List<Province> provinces = new ArrayList<Province>();
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "region")
@XmlTransient
private List<ActualiteRegion> actualites = new ArrayList<ActualiteRegion>();

public Long getIdRegion() {
    return idRegion;
}

public void setIdRegion(Long idRegion) {
    this.idRegion = idRegion;
}

public String getNomRegion() {
    return nomRegion;
}

public void setNomRegion(String nomRegion) {
    this.nomRegion = nomRegion;
}

public Region(String nomRegion) {

    this.nomRegion = nomRegion;
}

public Region() {
}

public List<Province> getProvinces() {
    return provinces;
}

public void setProvinces(List<Province> provinces) {
    this.provinces = provinces;
}

public List<ActualiteRegion> getActualites() {
    return actualites;
}

public void setActualites(List<ActualiteRegion> actualites) {
    this.actualites = actualites;
}

}


@Entity
@Table(name="T_PROVINCE")
public class Province implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idProvince;
@Column(name = "NOM_PROVINCE", nullable = false, length = 20, unique = true)
private String nomProvince;
@ManyToOne(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDREGION")
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="provinces")
private Region region;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "province")
@XmlTransient
private List<Ville> villes = new ArrayList<Ville>();

public Long getIdProvince() {
    return idProvince;
}

public void setIdProvince(Long idProvince) {
    this.idProvince = idProvince;
}

public String getNomProvince() {
    return nomProvince;
}

public void setNomProvince(String nomProvince) {
    this.nomProvince = nomProvince;
}

public Province(String nomProvince) {

    this.nomProvince = nomProvince;
}

public Province() {

}

public Region getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(Region region) {
    this.region = region;
}

public List<Ville> getVilles() {
    return villes;
}

public void setVilles(List<Ville> villes) {
    this.villes = villes;
}
}
```

And this my class RegionService :

```
@Component
@Path("/regions")
public class RegionServiceImpl implements IRegionService {
private IRegionDAO dao;

public void setDao(IRegionDAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}


public void addRegion(Region r) {
    dao.addRegion(r);
}

@Path("/{id}")
@GET
@Produces(value=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Region getRegionById(@PathParam(value = "id")Long idAb) {

    return dao.getRegionById(idAb);
}


public void deleteRegion(Region r) {
    dao.deleteRegion(r);
}


public void updateRegion(Region r) {
    dao.updateRegion(r);
}


public List<Region> getAllRegions() {
    return dao.getAllRegions();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html) which explains below annotations:

- @XmlInverseReference
- @MapsId
- @XmlTransient

to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help . I tried to adapt my beans "Region" and "Province" with the annotations @ XmlTransient and @ XmlInverseReference but I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you update both Entity? in order to see better each modifies